# Apache configuration problem with <Directory> and <Location>

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, directory

I'm stuck with a pretty nasty problem. I have a staging system here where only our customers and our company should have access to. This is done using the following configuration:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/example.com">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks -Indexes
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
    # our IP
    Allow from 4.3.2.1
    # PayPal IPN
    Allow from 216.113.191.33
#    Deny from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /srv/www/htdocs/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Now I want to make one URL public so everyone has access to it. As it is a URL I went for the `Location` directive. So I tried the following:

```
<Location /url/to/config.xml>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

But no matter which combination I'm trying for `Order`, it just won't work and the server is always asking for credentials. Am I missing something? As far as I understood the docs at apache.org, the Location directive is parsed after Directory and therefore should be able to override the access limitations.

Any idea/hint?

Comment: I forgot, it's an Apache 2.2.10 on openSUSE 11.1

Comment: Which browser are you accessing the site with? I ran into an issue where Google Chrome had problems trying to access example.com/private/public when example.com/private had http auth, but Firefox behaved as expected. Maybe you're running into the same issue.

Comment: I already tried different browsers including wget. I get a 401 everywhere :-(

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with multiple <Directory> blocks. Here is a link to the applicable apache documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html

I think the key items for your case are:

> **What to use When**
>
> Choosing between filesystem containers and webspace containers is actually quite easy. When applying directives to objects that reside in the filesystem always use <Directory> or <Files>. When applying directives to objects that do not reside in the filesystem (such as a webpage generated from a database), use <Location>.
>
> It is important to never use <Location> when trying to restrict access to objects in the filesystem. This is because many different webspace locations (URLs) could map to the same filesystem location, allowing your restrictions to be circumvented.

Also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin - specifically:

> Apart from <Directory>, each group is processed in the order that they appear in the configuration files. <Directory> (group 1 above) is processed in the order shortest directory component to longest. So for example, <Directory /var/web/dir> will be processed before <Directory /var/web/dir/subdir>. If multiple <Directory> sections apply to the same directory they are processed in the configuration file order. Configurations included via the Include directive will be treated as if they were inside the including file at the location of the Include directive.

I think this will work:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/example.com">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks -Indexes
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
    # our IP
    Allow from 4.3.2.1
    # PayPal IPN
    Allow from 216.113.191.33
#    Deny from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /srv/www/htdocs/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
<Directory "/srv/www/example.com/url/to/config.xml">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ok, according to "What to use when" I should be heading in the right direction. It's the perfect description of what I want to accomplish. The URL is not a "real" file but just a URL that is rewritten to an index.php. That's why I can't use another <Directory> section.

Comment: Can you include the rewrite rules as well?